# How is my Mac mini booting up Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, mac-mini

I just installed Ubuntu 14.10 on my 2012 Mac mini.  I did not do anything special during the installation process; I did not create a separate /boot partition.

During power up, the screen stays white for about 20-30 seconds, then Ubuntu boots up.

Is my Mac mini booting up using the legacy BIOS mode?

Comment: Macs don't have a BIOS. Most likely is your install overwrote the original partitioning & OS. Try holding the Opt key at the chines & see if there's still any Mac OS to choose from.

Comment: Tetsujin: I nuked OS X during installation because I wanted to single-boot Ubuntu.

Comment: Then it probably takes it that amount of time to figure out it doesn't have a standard setup to boot from. It's probably hunting for a clear indication of which boot volume to start from, which it expects to see no matter how many boot volumes it has - but no longer has one, so eventually finds ubuntu & boots to that. Because there's no BIOS, there's no pre-determined boot order, it's usually done in software, probably in the EFI, but I am uncertain that low down in the system..

Comment: If I hold down the Option/Alt key during boot, I see the Apple Startup Manager showing a single choice -- an icon with the text "Windows" below.

Comment: I think my issue is highly related to this Q&A -- http://askubuntu.com/questions/221010/ubuntu-on-mac-mini-and-refit .

Answer (score 0):

I have spent extensive research hours into the exact issue that your experiencing. Yes, your mac has booted via its "last effort", or "fallback mode" and used an emulated BIOS to boot. An OS booted in this manner cannot see any EFI interaction with the hardware.

Macs boot via EFI, some models look for a FAT partition with efi binaries, and some models (like my macbook) require an HFS partition with efi binaries. The latter does not follow the standard.

The boot order is programmed into the macs EEPROM, and that is how the mac knows where to look.

Here are some steps (i will not show you how to use each utility):

- boot from [rEFInd's **USB image**](http://sourceforge.net/projects/refind/files/0.8.7/refind-flashdrive-0.8.7.zip/download), by holding alt at boot
- use the rEFInd boot menu to boot your ubuntu installer (this ensures that the OS knows it booted via EFI)
- install efibootmgr from the official repos
- [use efibootmgr to manipulate](http://heeris.id.au/2014/ubuntu-plus-mac-pure-efi-boot-short-version/) the embedded EFI boot settings in the macs EEPROM

I have had great successes using the links above.